# How to create symfony form in case of standalone using Symfony Form Component?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

This is form class

```
  class SignInForm extends AbstractType
 {
  public function 
  buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('login')
        ->add('password')
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'signin';
}
 }
```

how to link with entity and send it to render? 
so need to be something like this:

```
 $form = $formFactory->create(new SignupForm(), $user);
 $view->form = $form->createView();
```

P/S i need to create form only through class not with builder

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your User entity have login and password field it should be possible to do it like this with a twig to show the fields and bind the request with the user, if that what you need then i can give you some example.

Comment: no, i mean other thing. 
documentation says that i just need to do  $form = $this->createForm(new SignIn, $user),  but what does "$this" mean in this context ? As i mentioned above, i use form-component with other framework not with Symfony

Comment: you need to extend the controller class, which have the createForm, public function createForm($type, $data = null, array $options = array())
    {
        return $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($type, $data, $options);
    } i never had to work with symfony form without the whole framework, but try to use the form factory , $formFactory = new FormFactory(FormRegistryInterface $registry, ResolvedFormTypeFactoryInterface $resolvedTypeFactory) with the correct parameter, then $formFactory->create(....)

Comment: @Nawfat Serrar - The poster is not using the framework, just the form component.  So stuff about twig and controllers ae not germane.

Comment: @yuklia - Read up on the form component configuration to see how to instantiate a form factory. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#configuration

Comment: @Cerad yep i understood that in his comment and answered in consequence thx.  You can put it as answered i guess with the comment

Answer (score 0):

you need to extend the controller class, which have the createForm,

```
public function createForm($type, $data = null, array $options = array()) { return $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($type, $data, $options); }
```

i never had to work with symfony form without the whole framework, but try to use the form factory

```
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactory();

$formFactory->create(....)
```

for more information as @Cerad linked http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#configuration

Comment: The problem is that you don't directly new the FormFactory.  You really need to use the FormFactory factory as it were.  $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactory();

Comment: @Cerad ah good to know, i will edit it for whoever needs it then, thanks.